# WIFEXITED combined with WIFSIGNALED

Tags: c++, child-process, unix

I am testing the `WIFEXITED` to see if a child process exited abnormally or normally. According to documentation, it should return a non-zero status for a child process that terminated normally.

```
#include <wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, const char* const* argv) {
    int *pointer=NULL;
    int status;
    pid_t pid=fork();
    if (pid==0) {
        std::cout << "Child is: " << getpid() << std::endl;
        if (argc>1) {
            std::cout << getpid() << "Going to crash myself" << std::endl;
            *pointer=1; //Segmentation fault as of null pointer dereference
        }
        else
            pointer=NULL; //Safe code
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Parent is: " << getpid() << std::endl;
        pid_t terminated=waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
        std::cout << "Child " << terminated << " exited ";
        if (WIFEXITED(status)) std::cout << "GOOD";
        else {
             std::cout << "BAD";
             // Is it worth here to also check for WIFSIGNALED or is it redundant?
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << getpid() << " exiting normally" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To test a normal exit, call it without arguments, and an abnormal exit with segmentation fault, call it with some parameters.

Furthermore, if I use `WIFSIGNALED` it detects correctly the bad status, then, what's the use for `WIFEXITED`?

Is it advisable to use **only** `WIFEXITED`, or do you advise also to use `WIFSIGNALED` for further checks? Is this combination useful or redundant?

Answer (score 2):

## WIFSIGNALED / WIFSTOPPED

If you get into the "BAD" case, you may want to check whether `WIFSIGNALED` is true or `WIFSTOPPED` is true.  `WIFSIGNALED` tells you if the program terminated with a signal (such as segv).  `WIFSTOPPED` tells you if the program is currently stopped (but not terminated).

If your child process can never be stopped, then you can assume that it terminated abnormally and not bother checking those macros.  In your particular example, your child will either segfault or exit right away, so it's unlikely that someone would be able to `kill -STOP` your process before it crashed.

Answer (score 1):

`fork()` has three cases:

- It returns 0 to the child process.
- It returns a process ID to the parent process.
- **If the fork failed,** it returns -1 and sets `errno`.

---

Please don't omit braces inconsistently.  It's especially hard to read when the `if` branch and the `else` branch have different styles.